# put label.new() below intestation

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I built an oscillator:

[image: the read boxes represent the perfect position of the labels]

I'd like to put a label just below the head of the title. I can easily modify the y axis but I'm not able to modify the x. How can I set label.new() in order to achieve this goal?

Comment: I would consider using a table if you want it to to stay in that same position always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the time of the first visible bar chart with [chart.left_visible_bar_time](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_chart%7Bdot%7Dleft_visible_bar_time).

From there, you can plot your label using `xloc.bar_time`.

You can also use `xloc.bar_index` like for applying an offset in bars:

```
// Track the first visible bar index

var firstBarIndex = 0

if time == chart.left_visible_bar_time
    firstBarIndex := bar_index

// Plot a label five bars after

if bar_index == firstBarIndex +5
    label.new(bar_index, high, "5th")
```

Nevertheless, as mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76249375/put-label-new-below-intestation#comment134463288_76249375), you may prefer to plot a table with `position.top_left` instead.